# Angular 5 handling ErrorObservable

Tags: angular, typescript

I was doing Authentication for my front end.

sending `ErrorObservable` but not sure how to correctly handle it.

first, a `verify()` used by `AuthGuard`

```
verify(): Observable<string> {
    //return this.http.get('/api/verify', this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());

    //Do not do remote api check if there is no token saved
    if(!localStorage.getItem('acToken')) {
        return ErrorObservable.create( 'No Token Found?');
    }

    //console.log('verifying Remote');
    return this.httpC.get<Observable<string>>(Utils.apiBaseUrl + '/oauth/scopes', this.extraHeader())
        .pipe(
            //tap(data => console.log(data)),
            catchError(Utils.handleError),
        );
}
```

second, `canActivate()` in the `AuthGuard`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean
{
    console.log('@' + state.url);

    return this._userService.verify()
        .map(
            data => {
                console.log('verify Data');
                // logged in so return true
                if (data !== null) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return true;
                }
                // error when verify so redirect to login page with the return url
                return this.defaultReject(state);
            },
            error => {
                //console.log('verify Error');
                // error when verify so redirect to login page with the return url
                console.log('@err ' + error);
                return this.defaultReject(state);
            }
        );
}
```

Every time `Verify()` return `"ErrorObservable.create( 'No Token Found?')"`, there will be red ERROR `"Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Token Found?"` in console; 
on the other hand, if the `HttpClient` inside the `Verify()` get `401`, it will not get a `"ERROR Error: Uncaught"`

Is there a correct way to catch that `ErrorObservable` without Uncaught?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `.map` the wrong way in your `canActivate` method. If you see the documentation for `.map` (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map). You are using `map` a bit like the `subscribe` method. `map` can only transform every value yielded by the observable into another, so you shouldn't pass it the second parameter (the function that handles errors). In fact, if you pass `map` a second parameter it'll act as the `this` reference in the projection function (the first parameter).

The problem here is that, when you return an `ErrorObservable` you can't really apply `map` to it, you've got to subscribe to handle the error. See it in this example, where `error` is a `ErrorObservable` created via `Observable.throw`:

```js
let error = Rx.Observable.throw("error!"); // create an ErrorObservable

error.map(data => console.log(data)); // this has no effect, as the observable won't emit values.

error.subscribe({
   next: value => console.log("value", value), // as previously, won't execute
   error: error => console.log("error", error) // will execute
});

// You also can:

error.map(data => console.log('data', data)).subscribe({
  next: value => console.log('result', value),
  error: error => console.log('other way of handling it', error)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.5.0/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

The `map` operator subscribes to the observable, but ignores errors (they pass through it).

However, you can chain both results, as demonstrated in my last example. This way you always catch an error and can act on it

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getBase().subscribe(
      (next: BaseInfo) => {
          if(next === undefined){
            console.log('next ', 'hmm?');// because handleError2 return of(result as T);
          }else {
              console.log('next ', next);
          }
      },
      error =>{
          console.log('err ', error);// won't fire unless handleError2 throw error
      },
      () => {
          console.log('complete');
      }
  );

getBase() {
    return this.httpC.get<BaseInfo>(environment.apiServerUri + '/base1', this.extraHeader())
        .pipe(
            catchError(Utils.handleError2<BaseInfo>('getBase', undefined))
        );
}

public static handleError2<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {
        console.error(error); // log to console instead
        ////throw(operation + ' failed'); // use this for subscribe(error:) to fire
        // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
        return of(result as T);
    };
}
```

After one and half month, I finally understand this issue.
It was my `handleError2` that catch the error but not throw.
Because my `handleError2` was not `'throw'` error back, the `'error'` function under the `getBase().subscribe()` won't fire.